# Control Versioning Enterprise Architect

Tags: svn, tfs, cvs, enterprise-architect

I have been searching about version controling for packages in Enterprise Architect and I found that EA is able to use version controling with CVS, SVN and TFS. I really haven't tried any of these and I am reading about all of them but I would like to know what do you thing is the most convenient way. I also will work in a team accesing councurrently the models

Comment: If you search this site for the [enterprise-architect] tag and Subversion and Baselines, you'll find some info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a read of the [Version Control Best Practices for Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/WhitePapers/Version_Control.pdf) white paper on the Sparx website. Come back with some more-specific questions if anything isn't clear.